# Не удается прочитать pdf-файл

Tags: python, pdf

Хочу извлечь все таблицы из pdf-файла. Для этого использую библиотеку `tabula`

Пользуюсь `jupyter-notebook`

```
!pip install tabula-py
!pip install tabula
conda install -c bioconda java-jdk
```

Команды установки проходят без ошибок. Но когда пытаюсь импортировать модуль, то возникает проблема

```
from tabula import read_pdf

pdfs = read_pdf('1.pdf', pages='all', multiple_tables=True)
```

Ошибка

```
Error from tabula-java:
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.

CalledProcessError: Command '['java', '-Djava.awt.headless=true', '-Dfile.encoding=UTF8', '-jar', '/Users/tatan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tabula/tabula-1.0.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar', '--pages', 'all', '--guess', '--format', 'JSON', '1.pdf']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка означает, что при запуске процесса `java`, исполняемый файл не был найден:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.

Проверить доступность можно запустив `java` в консоли (например, в `cmd`):

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_341"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_341-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.341-b10, mixed mode)
```

Скорее всего, у вас будет ошибка вида:

> 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
> program or batch file.

Решением будет добавить папку с `java` в переменные пути `PATH`

**1.** Открыть можно через поиск в меню пуска:

[image: Элемент списка]

**2.** Выбираем "Переменные среды...":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**3.** Меняем `Path` для текущего пользователя или для всех:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**4.** Добавляем путь к папке с `java`:

[image: Элемент списка]

**5.** Проверяем, для этого нужно перезапустить консоль/IDE (т.к. они при запуске подхватывают те переменные среды) и повторить запуск `java`